# Capitalizing values

Tags: javascript

I'm going to have to apologize for how simple this question is going to be. I am a literally on Chapter 2 trying to learn javascript, and only just preparing myself for what is to come.

My questions specifically refers to [Chapter 2 of Eloquent Javascript's](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#p_bJwHD1AmQW) section on Variables. In the websites JS sandbox it uses the example:

```
var luigisDebt = 140;
luigisDebt = luigisDebt - 35;
console.log(luigisDebt);
// → 105
105
```

Got it no problem! Test around a bit more:

```
var luigisDebt = 140;
luigisDebt = luigisDebt - 35;
luigisDebt = luigisDebt - 5
console.log(luigisDebt);
100
```

However if I mess around with the capitalization like this:

```
var luigisDebt = 140;
luigisDebt = luigisDebt - 35;
luigisDebt = luigisdebt - 5
console.log(luigisDebt);
95
```

My output becomes incorrect with 95, instead of the correct 100.

Thanks to other posts I've learned about [camelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564398/javascript-method-naming-lowercase-vs-uppercase), [constructer functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687223/when-should-i-name-things-with-initial-capital-letters?lq=1) and [PascalCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008230/what-is-the-best-practice-casing-style-for-javascript-why/15655521#15655521). But still can't figure out why my output changes with Upper and Lower case?

Comment: As `luigisdebt` is undefined in that context, the result should be 105. `luigisdebt` has probably been defined before and set to 100.

Comment: Did you assign value to `luigisdebt` before, you code should output `Uncaught ReferenceError: luigisdebt is not defined`

Comment: check how you define the lower case variable "luigisdebt"

Comment: @gy134340 I did not assign any value to "luigidebt". I was expecting an error as well, that's why I found this to be so weird. Oh just a side note the code environment in the link I provided is interactive.

Comment: @caoglish Do you think the "luigidebt" was defined in the sandbox's backstage?

Comment: @cdm is there anyway to check?

Comment: @vili how about you change the variable name, like: luigisDebt => luigisDebt11 ,luigisdebt => luigisdebt11. see what will happen.

Comment: @caoglish Yup that gave me what I was expecting. "ReferenceError: luigisdebt11 is not defined (line 3)" Does this mean that the "luigisdebt" was predefined?

Comment: @vili, it have to be defined in somewhere. console.log(luigisdebt) before ```var luigisDebt = 140;``` to see what's the value. and do the global search. This is why we do not use global variable because you do not know where global variable have been initialized.

Comment: That does make sense @caoglish! So could I assume that if I wrote this line of code in an external editor I should expect an immediate "ReferenceError:" instead of an incorrect output?

Comment: @vili Yes, it's what I mean.However, does not  mean that put the code in external editor. I mean that you should  put the code in different runtime enviroment. For example, copy the code in your developer mode console of any browser.

Comment: @caoglish I did just that and I receive an error. So I think I have my answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`luigisdebt` is not defined in your code, it should answer 105. define this before using it.

Comment: I understand that it is not defined in the code. Im looking more to understand how a lower cased "luigisdebt" subtracted 10 instead of 5. Also if this is caused by the sandbox environment of the book's website or if this is a kind of error I should keep an eye out for?

Comment: I believe that you are getting an error from some sandbox environment, kindly install node in your system and try.it won't throw error like this

Comment: Thank you, but the specific environment Im working in is for educational purposes and is from a book in the link I provided in the summary above. There is nothing for me to install.

Comment: follow tutorials point for nodeJs, there is online compiler provided.